# How to sort DataGrid column

Tags: c#, database, datagrid

I have a datagrid that contains data that retrived from a database, and the datagrid displays data in the same format as in the database.

One of the columns is DateFrom which is the column I would like to sort. Dateform stored in the database as Varchar, therefore is sorted alphabetically,for example 2/2004, 2/2008, 4/2003. I want to convert DatFrom to typ DateTime, and sort the values numerically before display in the datagrid.

Is there any way to do it?

Thanks

Aein

Answer (score 1):

I created a little demo table (test). Inserted some test dates and did a select query:

```
Create Table test(dt varchar(10))
Go
Insert Into test(dt)
Select '2/2004'
Union Select '2/2008'
Union Select '4/2003'
Go

Select *
From test
Order By Convert(datetime, '1/' + dt, 103)
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably wrap the column to implement the IComparable interface so you can provide a custom sort, [here is an example](http://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.dotnet.framework.windowsforms.controls/browse_frm/thread/95a4515285a7be7a/198c0aff2a96be6e?lnk=st&q=dotnet+custom+sorting+grid&rnum=4#198c0aff2a96be6e).

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you're asking here.  Let me know if I'm off base.  I think the easiest way to fix this is in the select statement to get your data from the database, but it might not necessarily be the *best* method.  Here's what I've come up with:

Since your "DateFrom" is in the format of "MM/yyyy", you won't be able to do a straight CAST() operation.  The best way to get a valid DATETIME value, that I can think of, is to parse the current DateFrom column and treat all dates as the first of the month, then you can set a Format of "MM/yyyy" on the datagrid column, and it will still render properly.  The CAST() statement could be something like this:

```
SET DATEFORMAT MDY

SELECT CAST(SUBSTRING(DateFrom, 0, CHARINDEX('/',DateFrom))
        + '/1/'
        + SUBSTRING(DateFrom, CHARINDEX('/',DateFrom) +1, 4) AS DATETIME) AS DateFrom
```

I know this isn't the most elegant method, but it should work as long as your date format is *consistent*.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understood your question. Nevertheless, what about to sort the rows on the SQL side with something like:

```
SELECT ...
ORDER BY Substring(DateFrom, CHARINDEX('/', DateFrom) + 1, 4) 
         + Lpad(DateFrom, 7, '0');
```

It will change the original 2/1999 to 199902/1999 so that it can be compared as string. The part after the slash is there just because I did not want to crop the string since it is not needed.

or

```
SELECT ...
ORDER BY Cast(int, 
              Substring(DateFrom, CHARINDEX('/', DateFrom) + 1, 4) 
       * 100 
       + Cast(int, 
              Substring(DateFrom, 1, CHARINDEX('/', DateFrom));
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys. I'll look into it. I have to drop this project for a while. I'll let you know if I could get it to work or not.